# Second owl carousel photo slider is not working :(

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

My first carousel slider works just fine, but the second won't show anything? Have changed the ID name, but not quite sure where to call for this new ID name?

Please help, any help would be amazing! :)

My index.html code is here: http://pastebin.com/4wsf3Rg2

The site is live at http://www.passiton.nz, you but without the second carousel attached.

Comment: For assistance purpose could you specify the lines to look at (310-344), or even better write a simpler example ( example :  http://jsfiddle.net/w3nd5gg8/ )

Comment: have you tried checking your console for an error? just sayin

Comment: @KimOliveros Console just displays local errors for displaying Shopify / Instagram widgets :/

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I recommend you post your code to http://jsfiddle.net, so that we can easily debug it. You should call your `owlCarousel()` once your DOM is ready. What you did with your inline javascript is correct. However, it's bad practice to include your chunk code of your `<script></script>` inside all over the place inside your html markup.

You should create your own javascript file, and put all your custom javascript in there.

Here is what I would do to initiate two owl carousel in one page: http://jsfiddle.net/o269c1ku/3/

As you can see, you can initialize your owl carousel as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#owl-gallery").owlCarousel();
  $("#owl-gallery2").owlCarousel();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there - sorry my first time using StackOverflow and haven't used JSFiddle before - I don't understand, I copied and pasted exactly what you had there, but the second carousel just refuses to show. Could another css/js file be blocking it? Thank you so much, any more tips? :)

Comment: Try to put your `owl.carousel.min.js` script right under jquery script, and above the `main.js`. Then move your `owlCarousel()` initialization into your `main.js`. There also a chance that your owl.carousel source code is outdated. Here is the one that I used: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js

Comment: It looks like you got it fixed. Did my answer relevant to your question? If so, please vote so other people will know that is the correct answer if they come across. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any rep to vote, but it was correct - thanks again!